# Count field incorrect syntax error

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

for the last several days i'm trying to connect to store procedure using ODBC.
This is my CRecordset code:

```
sp_insertSesMessageStore::sp_insertSesMessageStore(CDatabase* pdb)
 : CRecordset(pdb){
// Param Init
m_RETURN_VALUE = -1;
m_PROVIDER_IDParam = _T("");
m_BRANCH_IDParam = _T("");
m_ACCOUNTParam = _T("");
m_SES_USER_UNIQUE_IDParam = _T("");
m_DISPLAY_NAMEParam = _T("");
m_SMTP_ADDRESSParam = _T("");
m_MESSAGE_TYPE_IDParam = 0;
m_PRIORITYParam = 0;
m_SUBJECTParam = _T("");
m_SUMMARYParam = _T("");
m_TEMPLATE_IDParam = _T("");
m_BODY_TYPE_IDParam = 0;
m_TRACKING_IDParam = _T("");
m_EXPIRATION_TIMEParam = _T("");
m_SUBCATEGORY_IDParam = 0;
m_FOLDER_IDParam = 0;
m_NUM_ATTACHMENTSParam = 0;
m_ACCESS_IDParam = _T("");
m_FLAGSParam = 0;
m_FAVORITEParam = FALSE;
m_CERTIFIED_IDParam = _T("");
m_SECURE_RESPONSE_OTPParam = _T("");
m_MESSAGE_IDParam = _T("");
m_nParams = 24;

m_nDefaultType = snapshot;}
```

This is the DoDataExchange.

```
void sp_insertSesMessageStore::DoFieldExchange(CFieldExchange* pFX){
// RFX output param mapping
/*pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::outputParam);
RFX_Long(pFX, _T("[@RETURN_VALUE]"), m_RETURN_VALUE);*/

// RFX input param mapping
pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::inputParam);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@PROVIDER_ID]"), m_PROVIDER_IDParam, 3);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@BRANCH_ID]"), m_BRANCH_IDParam, 50);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@ACCOUNT]"), m_ACCOUNTParam, 255);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@SES_USER_UNIQUE_ID]"), m_SES_USER_UNIQUE_IDParam, 8);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@DISPLAY_NAME]"), m_DISPLAY_NAMEParam, 255);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@SMTP_ADDRESS]"), m_SMTP_ADDRESSParam, 255);
RFX_Int(pFX, _T("[@MESSAGE_TYPE_ID]"), m_MESSAGE_TYPE_IDParam);
RFX_Byte(pFX, _T("[@PRIORITY]"), m_PRIORITYParam);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@SUBJECT]"), m_SUBJECTParam, 255);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@SUMMARY]"), m_SUMMARYParam, 255);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@TEMPLATE_ID]"), m_TEMPLATE_IDParam, 255);
RFX_Int(pFX, _T("[@BODY_TYPE_ID]"), m_BODY_TYPE_IDParam);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@TRACKING_ID]"), m_TRACKING_IDParam, 255);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@EXPIRATION_TIME]"), m_EXPIRATION_TIMEParam, 16);
RFX_Int(pFX, _T("[@SUBCATEGORY_ID]"), m_SUBCATEGORY_IDParam);
RFX_Int(pFX, _T("[@FOLDER_ID]"), m_FOLDER_IDParam);
RFX_Int(pFX, _T("[@NUM_ATTACHMENTS]"), m_NUM_ATTACHMENTSParam);
RFX_LongBinary(pFX, _T("[@BODY]"), m_BODYParam);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@ACCESS_ID]"), m_ACCESS_IDParam, 255);
RFX_Long(pFX, _T("[@FLAGS]"), m_FLAGSParam);
RFX_Bool(pFX, _T("[@FAVORITE]"), m_FAVORITEParam);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@CERTIFIED_ID]"), m_CERTIFIED_IDParam, 100);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@SECURE_RESPONSE_OTP]"), m_SECURE_RESPONSE_OTPParam, 50);

// RFX input_output param mapping
pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::inoutParam);
RFX_Text(pFX, _T("[@MESSAGE_ID]"), m_MESSAGE_IDParam, 8);}

BOOL sp_insertSesMessageStore::ExecDirect(){
return Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, GetDefaultSQL(), CRecordset::executeDirect);}
```

This is the statement i'm passing.

```
CString sp_insertSesMessageStore::GetDefaultSQL(){
return _T("{CALL sp_insertSesMessageStore (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");}
```

This is an auto generated code from a tool i found on the web. 
I had isolated the problem, the cause of this exception is the CLongBinary member, can't find the issue, any suggestions?!

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Do the insert values on the stored procedure match the columns on the SES_MessageStore table? If you don't specify the columns you are inserting in the values must match them

Comment: That is the error: "Count field incorrect syntax error."
There is no problem with the values i used the same columns and the same values in a regular 'insert' statement that had to be changed to a store procedure.
we also tested the store procedure with dummy values with a new sql query.